# Correct approach of using embedded and reference in mongoid

Tags: mongodb, associations, mongoid

I'm building association as follow

`person embeds one address`

`address references one country`
`address references one province`

`country embeds many provinces`

Is above association is good? I'm too much confused how to build them. I don't know exact use of mongodb and mongoid for building association.

Main concern of mine is when to use embedded and when to use references associations?

Answer (score 5):

Schema design in MongoDB depends on how you will query the data and how you will update the data. There is no general hard rule to determine if an associations should be embedded or referenced. I suggest you have a look at [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) excellent article.

Concerning your suggested schema you could also make the country an attribute/field on a province document and do less normalization than you would in a relational database. It all depends on how you access your documents.

```
collection provinces:

{
   name : 'Alabama'
   country : 'United States'
}
```